# Select previous row from the given parameters

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 2022-01-11 |
| 1 | 22 | 2021-10-01 |
| 1 | 39 | 2019-02-11 |
| 1 | 21 | 2018-10-08 |
| 1 | 17 | 2018-09-19 |
| 1 | 18 | 2018-09-10 |
| 1 | 39 | 2017-03-20 |
| 1 | 36 | 2017-02-28 |
| 1 | 34 | 2017-02-14 |
| 1 | 31 | 2017-01-20 |
| 1 | 21 | 2016-11-17 |
| 1 | 17 | 2016-10-20 |

As you can see, the codes are repeating after a specific date difference. I want to obtain the rows previous to the largest time difference.

For instance:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 2021-10-01 |
| 1 | 39 | 2019-02-11 |

Should give me the output:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 39 | 2019-02-11 |

Since a significant difference exists between 2019 and 2021, I want the previous row that is available before the vast difference between the dates.

The output from the above data frame would be as follows:

| id | code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 2022-01-11 |
| 1 | 39 | 2019-02-11 |
| 1 | 39 | 2017-03-20 |

This is the code I tried, but it gives me only the first value for each time difference. I tried max, min, first and last, but it is giving me the same result:

NOTE: sel is the data frame here. I used it in previous calculations, so I am using the same name here.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

sel['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sel['date'], format='%Y%m%d') # convert date column to datetime

sel = sel.sort_values(by=['id', 'date']) # sort the dataframe by patient_id and date

sel['time_diff'] = sel.groupby('id')['date'].diff() # calculate time difference between consecutive rows for each patient

mask = (sel['time_diff'] >= timedelta(days=365)) | (sel['time_diff'].isnull()) # find rows where the time difference is greater than or equal to 1 year or null (first row for each id)

output_df = sel.loc[mask].groupby(['id', 'code']).agg({'date': 'max'}).reset_index() # select the rows where the mask is True and get the max date for each code for each patient

output_df = output_df[['id', 'code', 'date']] # select the desired columns
output_df
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want able to solve this using the following code:

```
# import the datetime module
import datetime

# create a copy of the DataFrame and sort by ID and date in descending order
df = colu
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending=[True,False])

# initialize the final indices with the first row index and the current index to 0
final_indices = [0]
current_indice = 0

# iterate over each row in the DataFrame (except the last one)
for i in range(len(df['id']) - 1):
    # calculate the time difference in days between the current row's date and the date at the current index
    delta = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(df['date'].loc[df.index[current_indice]]), "%Y%m%d") - datetime.datetime.strptime(str(df['date'].loc[df.index[i+1]]), "%Y%m%d")
    
    # if the time difference is greater than 365 days, add the current row index to the final indices list
    # and update the current index to the current row index
    if(delta.days > 365):
        final_indices.append(i+1)
        current_indice = i+1

# select only the rows in the DataFrame with the final indices
df = df.loc[df.index[final_indices]]

# return the resulting DataFrame
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works:

```
# see the ascending param
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending=[True,False]) # sort the dataframe by patient_id and date

time_diff = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff() # calculate time difference between consecutive rows for each patient

# see the different comparison
mask = (time_diff < pd.Timedelta(days=-365)) | time_diff.isna() # find rows where the time difference is greater than or equal to 1 year or null (first row for each id)

# just mask here
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
   id  code       date
0   1    37 2022-01-11
2   1    39 2019-02-11
6   1    39 2017-03-20
```

Comment: Hi Quang, I tried to run it on a different id and I am getting this error: 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'


9 mask = (time_diff < pd.Timedelta(days=-365)) | time_diff.isna() 


I checked the data type and its pandas series. 
I changed the code a bit and its not working.

Comment: *I changed the code a bit* -> what did you change? Also, you don't need to *run it on a different id*, it should work for the big dataframe with all ids.

Comment: one_year_ago = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(days=-365)] * len(time_diff), index=time_diff.index)
mask = (time_diff > one_year_ago) | (time_diff.isna().values)

But it still gives me the same error. 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'

Comment: In addition, I noticed that some ids don't have a yearly difference. And at that point, the code crashed.

Comment: what did you do to `time_diff`? If not, then the error is somewhere else, not that line.

Comment: df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'], ascending=[True,False]) # sort the dataframe by id and date
time_diff = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff() 

# find rows where the time difference is greater than or equal to 1 year or null (first row for each id)
mask = (time_diff < pd.Timedelta(days=-365)) | time_diff.isna() 

# exclude rows where the time difference is less than or equal to 1 year
mask_exclude = ((time_diff >= pd.Timedelta(days=-365)) & (time_diff <= pd.Timedelta(days=0)))
mask = mask & ~mask_exclude

# filter the dataframe using the mask
result = df[mask]